# How to return function in kotlin poet

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinpoet

I'm using KotlinPoet for annotation processing, but I've got an issue. I need return function in generated class, but I'm not sure that KotlinPoet can do it? If you have some experience, please help me.

That I can do:

```
fun test(): String = ...
```

That I need to do

```
fun test(): () -> String = ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to `ClassName` or `TypeName`, you can use [`LambdaTypeName`](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/0.x/kotlinpoet/com.squareup.kotlinpoet/-lambda-type-name/index.html) to create a function type with no parameters and `String` return type:

```
val type = LambdaTypeName.get(returnType = String::class.asTypeName())
```